# C++ do...while Boolean

Tags: c++, loops

How can I have a number entered set a Boolean false.
For example here's my boolean:

```
childUpset= true
do
// do stuff while childUpset is true

// then enter 7 to make childUpset false
while (childUpset =! true);
//this is my last while loop
```

Comment: `if (i == 7) childUpset = false;` ?

Comment: Why don't you try something?

Comment: I suggest you learn some c++ before trying to program in c++.

Answer (score 2):

use cin to get the entered number by the user

```
childUpset = true;
do {
 cout<<"Enter Number:";
 cin>>num;
 if (num == 7){
    childUpset = false;
 }

 }
while(childUpset == true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i;
  bool childUpset = true;
  do{
    cin >> i;
    if (i==7) childUpset =false;
  }while (childUpset == true);
  return 0;
}
```

(You may get vote down if ask kind of these questions. Be carefull)

Answer (score 1):

```
childUpset= true
do{
 int number;
 cin >> number;
 if (number == 7) childUpset = false;
}
while (childUpset)
```